# Proof of the following inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations

let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n$ be positive numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=n$, we denote $S=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n)$. For a given set of $m\geq n$ vectors $f_1,f_2,...,f_m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^mf_if_i^T=S$$
I need to prove that
$$∥S^{−1}f_i∥∥f_i∥\leq1$$
can anyone help me to prove it plz. In case $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=...=\lambda_n$ I've already proved it and also
$$∥S^{−1/2}f_i∥\leq1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I missed something :

Let $n=m=2$, $f_1 =(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} , \frac{\sqrt{7}}{4})$, $f_2 =(\frac{\sqrt{21}}{4},-\frac{1}{4})$, $\lambda_1 = 3/2$ and $\lambda_2 = 1/2$.
We have that  $\|S^{-1} f_1\|\|f_1\|>1$.

Isn't that a counterexample ?

Comment: yeah thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look i think there is an error in your Exercise, to prove that i will consider the case in which $m=n$, here S is a Positive definite matrix, so i will consider Dot product associate to S and i will prove that $(f_1,...,f_n)$ is an orthonormal basis for this product,
So from the given equality, and for any vector x we have :
$$\sum_{i=1}^nf_i<f_i,x>=Sx⇒\sum_{i=1}^nS^{-1}f_i<f_i,x>=x$$
Then we put $e_i=S^{-1}f_i$, we have :
$$\sum_{i=1}^n<Se_i,x>e_i=\sum_{i=1}^n<e_i,x>_Se_i=x$$
And this for any x, Which means that $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis for the Dot product associate to S (Which we note $< , >_S$),
Particularly We have :
$$<e_i,e_i>_S=<S^{-1}f_i,f_i>=1$$ And By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have :
$$1=<S^{-1}f_i,f_i>⩽\Vert{S^{-1}f_i}\Vert\Vert{f_i}\Vert$$
You See !!

Comment: if $(f_1,...,f_n)$ is an orthonormal  basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\Vert f_i\Vert= \Vert S^{-1}f_i\Vert=1$

Comment: Sorry the orthonormal basis is $(e_1,...,e_n)$ just a frappe fault, see my proof above !

Comment: $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is orthonormal basis is equivalent to say that $(f_1,...,f_n)$ is orthonormal basis. I saw your proof there is not contradiction with my statement and as I mentioned in this case $\Vert f_i\Vert= \Vert S^{-1}f_i\Vert=1$

Comment: ok @Nizar i'll try to improve my proof !